# Can SpEL expressions be used for ternary expression assignment in the configuration of @ReactiveFeginClient for value and url

Tags: java, openfeign, reactive-feign-client

I want to achieve this configuration, or are there any other solutions?

```yaml
server-map:
  push-sever:
    name: http://xxxx
    url: http:///
    use-name: true
```

```java
 @ReactiveFeginClient(value="${${server-map.push-sever.use-name}?${server-map.push-sever.name}:''}",
url="${${server-map.push-sever.use-name}?${server-map.push-sever.url}:''}")
```

I tried to configure the ternary expression of SpEL, but it seems that it cannot be configured properly. It reads the entire parameter and turns it into a string like "true?http://xxxxx:''", and cannot be executed properly.

Comment: `${}` refers to a spring placeholder. if you want to use spel, the outer layer should be `#{}`

Comment: I tried it and the generated content in the exception message is like "#{true?http://xxxxx:''}", it seems that SpEL syntax is not supported.

Comment: Well, maybe you can set this value somewhere else using the ternary operator, then using spring spel to refer to the value of this variable

Comment: Well, I implemented it with a WebClient instead